# Expressive power of lambda-calculus with restricted application

Tags: computability, lambda-calculus

Consider a syntactic restriction of the (untyped) $\lambda$-calculus in which an application cannot have another application as an immediate subterm. More precisely, *restricted terms* ($R,S,...$) and *non-application restricted terms* ($N,O,...$) are given mutually recursively by the grammar:
$$
  R, S, ... ::= N \,\mid\, N\,N \\
  N, O, ... ::= x \,\mid\, \lambda x.N
$$
Equivalently:
$$
  R, S, ... ::= x
       \,\mid\, \lambda x. R
       \,\mid\, x\,y
       \,\mid\, x\,(\lambda y.R)
       \,\mid\, (\lambda x.R)\,y
       \,\mid\, (\lambda x.R)\,(\lambda y.S)
$$
It can be checked that restricted terms are closed by $\beta$-reduction under arbitrary contexts.

What is the expressive power of this restricted $\lambda$-calculus (with $\beta$-reduction)? Can it express all computable functions? Remark that this restriction is not strong enough to guarantee termination; e.g. the non-terminating term $\Omega := (\lambda x. x\,x)\,(\lambda x. x\,x)$ is a restricted term.

Comment: Hi Pablo, the usual route to Turing completeness uses fixpoint combinators.  Here, I have a hard time seeing how these may work because the ones I am aware of are all applications, so you can't use them in the restricted framework (if $Y$ is a fixpoint combinator which is an application, when you want to find the fixpoint of an arbitrary term $F$ you'd write $YF$, which is not allowed).  So a first question would be whether non-application restricted fixpoint combinators exist...  I have no idea, but quite a lot is known about fixpoint combinators, so maybe someone has an answer :-)